# How does Mirai infect IoT?

Tags: malware, iot

Since every IoT device uses different operating system, and has different hardware architecture, with so many possible platforms, how does Mirai infect them?

Comment: I doubt your claims so you might add some references which prove these. In my opinion Mirai does not infect all IoT device but only specific devices. Also not every IoT uses a different OS but most use Linux with busybox or similar and then there are some others. And there are also not too much hardware architectures to care of.

Comment: @william your question still makes the assumption that Mirai infects multiple different operating systems. Do you have any reference that this is the case?

Comment: @william007 did this resolve your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, the Mirai virus was looking for a *specific* vulnerability present in the Linux operating system.

The Mirai virus targeted Linux devices running telnet via busybox. If busybox is not installed on the Linux device, the exploit fails as Mirai uses busybox specific commands. If busybox is confirmed to exists, Mirai then performs a bruteforce attack on specific ports numbers that are running telnet. How is this bruteforce attack being conducted? It is simply using a dictionary of the most common *default* username and password combinations. Once inside the system, Mirai looks for other target machines to infect. Here is a list of the Mirai's dictionary. [image]

Unfortunately, many owners of IoT devices connect their devices to the Internet and never bothered to change the default login credentials. Here is a list of devices targeted by Mirai. [image] More information can be found on the Mirai virus [here](https://www.malwaretech.com/2016/10/mapping-mirai-a-botnet-case-study.html).

Comment: Regarding "and never bothered to change the default login credentials" -- many of the devices being targeted by Mirai have (or had) hard-coded telnet account passwords that could not be changed by the user.

Comment: Good answer, but how I know which devices have linux with `busybox` installed at home?

Comment: @ruffp Simply type `busybox` in the command line. If this executes successfully, busybox is on the machine. However, please be aware that busybox is not the culprit here. A new flavor of Mirai could target a Linux distribution without busybox.

Comment: @GavinYouker thanks for your answer, but for example TV's, PVR's, and things like this, I have no idea if I can reach it by SSH myself (never tried); Just wanted to know if there's a list of potential hardware that uses linuxes as an internal OS.

Comment: @ruffp Check the updated answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: What about Windows operating system? Linux operating system is far more secure than Windows. Doesn't it make sense to infect Windows machines?

Comment: This bruteforce attack is equally as effective on Windows as it is on Linux. However, most IoT devices and routers are Linux based. This is one reason Mirai targeted BusyBox. For Mirai to infect IoT devices it first has to infect the router. Nearly all routers are Linux based.

Comment: Additionnaly there is this site: http://iotscanner.bullguard.com/ that can help to scan your public IP.

Comment: @ruffp I did not know that... Thanks for the info!

Comment: For my latest comment, note it is just a scanner for open port (another well known is [here](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?rh1dkyd2)) and it does not necessary means because the port is open that your are infected by Mirai.

Comment: @GavinYouker according to your comment on 21 Dec, does it means Mirai once he infects a router it will start to scan the whole internet for other router to infect but also the internal network to find other IoT devices? If this is the case, the internal network traffic would be higher than usual and then detectable no?

Comment: To my knowledge - yes this would be more detectable. Many viruses use this same technique to spread themselves. I believe the virus isn't hard to detect. Rather, many users don't monitor their traffic or set up intrusion detection systems (due to lack of knowledge or not caring). If you want to play with this concept yourself you can find the open source of Mirai.